# How to change value of immutable object

Tags: scala, closures, immutability

```
val factor = 3
val multiplier = (i:Int) => i * factor
```

if I call  `multiplier(3)` it will give us an output `9`.

What I want is

```
multiplier(3)
output =9
multiplier(3)
output=6
```

How to change multiplier for this type of functionality as factor is immutable?

Comment: you can't modify factor as its declared as val. I am not sure what you exactly want but why not i*(factor-1) ?

Comment: [Referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). It's a rather important concept in FP circles.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about how you want `multiplier` to work? Why does it return `*3` the first time and `*2`  the second time? What should happen the third time?

Comment: I really suspect you don't have to change anything, possible approach is to use currying .. https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/currying.html

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the value of an immutable object. That is *literally* what the English word "immutable" means: unchangeable. The whole point of functional programming is that you *never* change objects, you only return new ones.

Answer (score -1):

No idea if this is a good idea

```
val factor = 3

// all this Wrap stuff is so that we don't have an implicit Int
class Wrap(var inner: Int)
implicit val tmp = new Wrap(factor + 1)
def multiplier(i: Int)(implicit w: Wrap) = { w.inner -= 1; w.inner * i }
```

and substitute `w.inner -= 1` for other functionality if you want it. Or without implicits

```
class Wrap(var inner: Int)
var tmp = new Wrap(factor + 1)

def base(i: Int)(w: Wrap) = { w.inner -= 1; i * w.inner }
def multiplier(i: Int) = base(i)(tmp)
```

both do

```
multiplier(3)  // 9
multiplier(3)  // 6
multiplier(3)  // 3
```

Both ways need the creation of a var. Can't see how else you can do it without getting complicated.

Comment: I'd be interested to know which part of this got the downvote and why